# .NET Core 3.1 - SAP Connector - Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.VirtualPathExtension'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-3.1, sap-dotnet-connector

I have a `.NET Core 3.1` Application that's hosting REST services and I'm incorporating the SAP Connector utilities for some of the endpoints. I'm on Windows 10.

I'm running into an error through one of the endpoints when establishing new `RfcConfigParameters` by doing `RfcConfigParameters parameters = new RfcConfigParameters()`

The error trace is as follows:

```
2022-01-14 12:49:41.982 -05:00 [ERR] LookupRfcAttributes Error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.VirtualPathExtension' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters.LoadConfiguration()
   at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters..cctor()
2022-01-14 12:49:42.781 -05:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred, The type initializer for 'SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters' threw an exception.
System.Exception: The type initializer for 'SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters' threw an exception.
   at SAPConnector.API.Services.SAPService.LookupRfcAttributes(AttributeLookupRequest attributeRequest) in C:\Users\nbaki.DOMARI\Projects\SAPConnector\SAPConnector.API\Services\SAPService.cs:line 55
   at SAPConnector.API.Controllers.SAPController.AttributeLookup(LookupRequest lookupRequest) in C:\Users\nbaki.DOMARI\Projects\SAPConnector\SAPConnector.API\Controllers\SAPController.cs:line 221
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.SwaggerUiIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.RedirectToIndexMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at CorrelationId.CorrelationIdMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, ICorrelationContextFactory correlationContextFactory)
   at SAPConnector.API.Middleware.ApiExceptionHandlingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\nbaki.DOMARI\Projects\SAPConnector\SAPConnector.API\Middleware\ApiExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 32
```

I have followed so many articles & guides on fixing issues similar to this and have not been able to resolve it. I have enabled/disabled all Windows features. I have removed `ServiceModel` from the IIS Modules. I even disabled .NET 3.5 completely feeling as though there's a conflict. I have tried registering .NET v4 through `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` but it tells me manage this through "Windows Features" or through "dism", which I have done.

Below are some screenshots that could help aid my question:

[image: Windows Features]
[image: IIS Management Console]
[image]

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>dism /online /get-features

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19042.1415

Features listing for package : Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.19041.1

Feature Name : Printing-PrintToPDFServices-Features
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Printing-XPSServices-Features
State : Enabled

Feature Name : TelnetClient
State : Disabled

Feature Name : TFTP
State : Disabled

Feature Name : LegacyComponents
State : Disabled

Feature Name : DirectPlay
State : Disabled

Feature Name : SimpleTCP
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Windows-Identity-Foundation
State : Disabled

Feature Name : NetFx3
State : Disabled with Payload Removed

Feature Name : WCF-HTTP-Activation
State : Disabled

Feature Name : WCF-NonHTTP-Activation
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-WebServerRole
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-WebServer
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpErrors
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpRedirect
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-Security
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-RequestFiltering
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-NetFxExtensibility
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpLogging
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-LoggingLibraries
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-RequestMonitor
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpTracing
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-URLAuthorization
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-IPSecurity
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-Performance
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-WebServerManagementTools
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ManagementScriptingTools
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-Metabase
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WAS-WindowsActivationService
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WAS-ProcessModel
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WAS-NetFxEnvironment
State : Disabled

Feature Name : WAS-ConfigurationAPI
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HostableWebCore
State : Disabled

Feature Name : WCF-Services45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WCF-HTTP-Activation45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WCF-TCP-Activation45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WCF-Pipe-Activation45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WCF-MSMQ-Activation45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WCF-TCP-PortSharing45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-StaticContent
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-DefaultDocument
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-DirectoryBrowsing
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-WebDAV
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-WebSockets
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ApplicationInit
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ASPNET
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ASPNET45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ASP
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-CGI
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ISAPIExtensions
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ISAPIFilter
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ServerSideIncludes
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-CustomLogging
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-BasicAuthentication
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ManagementConsole
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-ManagementService
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-WMICompatibility
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-LegacyScripts
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-LegacySnapIn
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-FTPServer
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-FTPSvc
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-FTPExtensibility
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-Container
State : Enabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-DCOMProxy
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-Server
State : Enabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-ADIntegration
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-HTTP
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-Multicast
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MSMQ-Triggers
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-CertProvider
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-WindowsAuthentication
State : Enabled

Feature Name : IIS-DigestAuthentication
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication
State : Disabled

Feature Name : IIS-ODBCLogging
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MediaPlayback
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WindowsMediaPlayer
State : Enabled

Feature Name : DataCenterBridging
State : Disabled

Feature Name : SmbDirect
State : Enabled

Feature Name : HostGuardian
State : Disabled

Feature Name : SearchEngine-Client-Package
State : Enabled

Feature Name : MSRDC-Infrastructure
State : Enabled

Feature Name : TIFFIFilter
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
State : Enabled

Feature Name : MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2
State : Enabled

Feature Name : NetFx4-AdvSrvs
State : Enabled

Feature Name : NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
State : Enabled

Feature Name : SMB1Protocol-Deprecation
State : Enabled

Feature Name : MultiPoint-Connector
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MultiPoint-Connector-Services
State : Disabled

Feature Name : MultiPoint-Tools
State : Disabled

Feature Name : AppServerClient
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Windows-Defender-Default-Definitions
State : Enabled

Feature Name : WorkFolders-Client
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Client-ProjFS
State : Disabled

Feature Name : SMB1Protocol
State : Enabled

Feature Name : SMB1Protocol-Client
State : Enabled

Feature Name : SMB1Protocol-Server
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Printing-Foundation-Features
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Printing-Foundation-InternetPrinting-Client
State : Enabled

Feature Name : Printing-Foundation-LPDPrintService
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Printing-Foundation-LPRPortMonitor
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-DeviceLockdown
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-EmbeddedShellLauncher
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-EmbeddedBootExp
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-EmbeddedLogon
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-KeyboardFilter
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Client-UnifiedWriteFilter
State : Disabled

Feature Name : ServicesForNFS-ClientOnly
State : Disabled

Feature Name : ClientForNFS-Infrastructure
State : Disabled

Feature Name : NFS-Administration
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
State : Disabled

Feature Name : HypervisorPlatform
State : Disabled

Feature Name : VirtualMachinePlatform
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Containers-DisposableClientVM
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Tools-All
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-PowerShell
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Services
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients
State : Disabled

Feature Name : DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Windows-Defender-ApplicationGuard
State : Disabled

Feature Name : Containers
State : Disabled

The operation completed successfully.
```

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Both enable .net 3.5 and 4.8 is better. Then use `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` to install the version of ASP.NET that is associated with Aspnet_regiis.exe and only registers ASP.NET in IIS.

Comment: @BruceZhang I mentioned that doing the `-iru` registration didn't work. See also the associated command line screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is not what you would like to hear, but please check the release and support strategy of NCo 3.0. It says:

> The supported Microsoft **.NET Frameworks** are 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5,
> 4.6, 4.7, and 4.8.

This means **.NET Core** is not supported at all by NCo. .NET Core is not the same as the classic .NET framework. If your application must be a .NET Core application, I doubt that you will be able to use the current SAP NCo at all then.

Unfortunately, SAP also did not announce any NCo version for .NET Core environments yet.

Comment: Thanks @Trixx. I actually noticed this exact problem the next day after I posted this question. And now I'm on the path of converting my .NET Core 3.1 to .NET Framework 4.8